# I need to put resize image 150x130

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, upload

I need help with image resize I don't know how to put in

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['newcover'])) {

    ////GET image uploading settings
    $select_upload_options = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM covers_submit_options");
    $uop = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_upload_options);

    $poster = $uop['cover_who_post'];
    $approve = $uop['cover_approve'];
    $server = $uop['cover_server'];
    $default_user = $uop['cover_default_user'];


    $cover_title = $_POST['title'];
    $cover_desc = $_POST['desc'];
    $cover_desc2 = $_POST['desc2'];
    $cover_date = $_POST['date'];
    $cover_tags = $_POST['tags'];
    $cover_okvir = $_POST['okvir'];
    $cover_velicina = $_POST['velicina'];
    $cover_image2 = $_POST['image2'];

    $cover_category = $_POST['huge'];
    if ($poster != 'user' && $_SESSION['userid'] == '') {
        $poster_user = $default_user;
    } else {
        $poster_user = $_SESSION['userid'];
    }


    if ($cover_title == '') {
        $post_error = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><h3>Unesite Ime i Prezme</h3></div>';
    } elseif ($cover_category == '') {
        $post_error = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><h3>Izaberite Grad ii Općinu</h3></div>';
    } elseif ($cover_date == '') {
        $post_error = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><h3>Unesite Datum-Godište Npr. 1965-2016</h3></div>';
    } elseif ($cover_okvir == '') {
        $post_error = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><h3>Izaberite Izgled Osmrtnice</h3></div>';
    } elseif ($poster_user == '') {
        $poster_user = '1';
    } elseif ($_FILES['photo']['size'] == '1') {
        $post_error = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><h3>Please Select Image</h3></div>';
    } else {
        $post_error = '';
    }


    if ($post_error == '') {
        if ($server == 'amazon') {
            ////////UPLOAD TO AMAZON/////////////////////
            include('includes/amazonUpload.php');

            ////////UPLOAD TO AMAZON/////////////////////
        } else {
            ////////////REGULAR UPLOADER TO SERVER/////////

            list($file, $error) = upload('photo', 'images/covers/', 'jpg,jpeg,gif,png');

            list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = ('images/covers/' . $file);
            ////////////Da bi upload slike mogao da radi uklonio sam dio koda orginal kod je ovaj dolje   getimagesize  prije zagrade images/covers /////////


            if ($width < 0 || $height < 0) {
                $post_error = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><h3>The Cover is Small<br>Please note that the Minimum allowed hight is 300px and Minimum Width is 800px </h3></div>";
                unlink('images/covers/' . $file);
            } else {
                $image = 'images/covers/' . $file;
            }
            ////////////REGULAR UPLOADER TO SERVER/////////
            $error = $post_error;
        }

        ////Store Into Database
        if (!$error) {

            $string = $slug;

            if (strlen($string) != mb_strlen($string, 'utf-8')) {
                $slug = date("M-D-His");
            } else {

                $slug = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]/", '', $cover_title);
                //$slug = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $cover_title);
                $slug = strtolower($slug);
            }
            $is_slug_exists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM covers_posts WHERE post_slug = '$slug' ");
            $slug_exsits = mysql_num_rows($is_slug_exists);

            if ($slug_exsits != '0') {
                $slug = $slug . '-' . date('sy');
            } else {
                $slug = $slug;
            }


            $cover_datum = date("d-m-Y");
            $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO covers_posts VALUES ('',
                 '$cover_title',
                  '$cover_desc',
                   '$cover_desc2',
                    '$cover_date',
                     '$cover_tags',
                      '$cover_okvir',
                       '$cover_velicina',
                    '$slug',
                    '$image',
                    '$cover_image2',
                    '$cover_category',
                    '1',
                    '$poster_user',
                    '$approve',
                    '0',
                    '0',
                    '0',
                    '$cover_datum'
                    ) ");


            order_badge($poster_user);



            $post_error = '<div class="alert alert-success"><h3>Uspješno Ste Dodali Osmrtnicu , Prebacit će vas za  5 sekundi<br>
                Ukolko ste zastali <a href="osmrtnica-' . $slug . '.html">Kliknite Ovde</a>
                </h3></div>';
            $redir = 'osmrtnica-' . $slug . '.html';
            redirect($redir, '5');
        } else {
            $post_error = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><h3>' . $error . '</h3></div>';
        }
    } else {
        $post_error = $post_error;
    }
    $smarty->assign('UploadResult', $post_error);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Start here [Its called the manual, Shh, it's a secret, dont tell anybody else you now know where it is](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Comment: **Stop** usinf deprecated `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

ok I know it is older script and I changed later in mysqli connection.
I read manual about upload and resize image now it is resize image but all image are black

```
 elseif ($cover_okvir == '') {
        $post_error = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><h3>Izaberite Izgled Osmrtnice</h3></div>';
    }
    elseif ($poster_user == '') {
        $poster_user = '1';
    }else{

            ////////////REGULAR UPLOADER TO SERVER/////////

            list($file,$error) = upload('photo','images/covers/','jpg,jpeg,gif,png');

            list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize('images/covers/'.$file);

                  $width = 140;
                   $height = 150;
            ////////////REGULAR UPLOADER TO SERVER/////////

        $src = imagecreatefromstring('images/covers/'.$file);
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
imagecopyresampled($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$width,$height);
imagedestroy($src);
imagepng($dst,'images/covers/'.$file); // adjust format as needed
imagedestroy($dst);

}
        $image = 'images/covers/'.$file;
    enter code here
```